# How can i sort this array on groupscore?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

```
0: {id: 2575, groepName: "ezeez-1", groupScore: 50, Players: Array(0)}
1: {id: 2574, groepName: "ezeez-2", groupScore: 25, Players: Array(0)}
2: {id: 2576, groepName: "ezeez-3", groupScore: 10, Players: Array(0)}
3: {id: 2577, groepName: "ezeez-4", groupScore: 100, Players: Array(0)}
```

I want to sort this array on groupScore i watched some other stackoverflow questions about this but wasnt very clear for my anybody who can help ?

```
    sortgroup(){
          var i = 0;
          var i2 = 1;
          if (  this.lobbygroups[i].groupScore < this.lobbygroups[i2].groupScore ){
            return -1;
          }
          if ( this.lobbygroups[i].groupScore > this.lobbygroups[i2].groupScore ){
            return 1;
          }
i++;
i2++:
          return 0;
        }   
    }
    this.lobbygroepen.sort(sortgroup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{id: 2575, groepName: "ezeez-1", groupScore: 50, Players: Array(0)},
{id: 2574, groepName: "ezeez-2", groupScore: 25, Players: Array(0)},
{id: 2576, groepName: "ezeez-3", groupScore: 10, Players: Array(0)},
{id: 2577, groepName: "ezeez-4", groupScore: 100, Players: Array(0)}];

var sortData = data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    return b.groupScore > a.groupScore ? 1: -1;
  });

console.log(sortData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```